# Make MSBuild detect and extract errors and warnings of non-ms tools

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

When MSBuild build completes, the driver extracts warning and error messages and prints an error summary. However it only recognizes the error format it itself and Microsoft compilers use. But we also build for other platforms where the errors are from CLang, Make and Javac, each in different format.

Is there a way to tell MSBuild to recognize those errors, or, alternately, something that would translate the other errors to the Microsoft format so they get to the summary?

The full log is really long, and worse, the TFS build server does not show all of it, only the messages that were recognized as certain severity levels, so accessing the errors from cross-platform builds is quite a bit of extra work.

Answer (score 6):

In your Msbuild files you're likely using `<exec>` to call these other tools. You can add the following attributes to the exec tag:

```
IgnoreStandardErrorWarningFormat=true 
CustomErrorRegularExpression="^ERROR" 
CustomWarningRegularExpression="^WARN"
```

Unfortunately you'll loose the option to include filename and line numbers so Visual Studio and Team Build will not be able to jump to the violating file from the logs.

Comment: VS uses a `<filename>(<line>): error <code>: <message>` format to recognize file/line numbers so if that would be required one could use a custom logger which parses each log line and transfroms clang/cmake/... errors into this format.